# Nested loops in ansible - Vcloud director

Tags: ansible

Following is a ansible task which returns a list virtual machines in VCD vapp. I am storing the results in a variable "all_vms".

```
- name: List VMs of VCD VAPP
  vcd_vapp:
    vapp_name: test
    host: lab.vcd
    operation: "list_vms"
  register: all_vms
```

The output of the variable "all_vms" is a list of dictionary like below:

```
  "msg": [
        {
            "deployed": true,
            "ip_address": "192.168.0.151",
            "name": "esxi-67u1-1",
            "status": "POWERED_ON"
        },
        {
            "deployed": true,
            "ip_address": "192.168.0.150",
            "name": "vcsa-67u1",
            "status": "POWERED_ON"
        }
    ]
```

I need to check if the status of all the VMs is POWERED_ON, if not all I need to repeat the task above. How can I do this?

I tried blocks but I can not loop over blocks? Would appreciate some pointers on how retry a task based on the returned output.

```
  block:
      - name: List VMs of VCD VAPP
        vcd_vapp:
          vapp_name: test
          host: labs.vcd
          operation: "list_vms"
        register: all_vms
      - name: Check if VMs are powered on
        set_fact:
          poweron_pending = "yes"
        loop: "{{ all_vms.msg }}"
        when: item.status != "POWERED_ON"
    until: poweron_pending == "yes"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decide to use `until` you will also have to set a maximum loop with `retries`. I think you can achieve that in a single task by filtering the results with [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) and counting them, repeating the task until you get an empty list.

Here is the general idea:

```
- name: List VMs of VCD VAPP
  vcd_vapp:
    vapp_name: test
    host: lab.vcd
    operation: "list_vms"
  register: all_vms
  retries: 100
  until: >-
    {{ all_vms | json_query("[?status!='POWERED_ON']") | length == 0 }}
```

Disclaimer: I don't have vcd to test. I only tested my query against your mentionned data structure. Using `retries/until` might alter your registered var and you may have to adjust the above json query to the exact data structure.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator, the solution works. But just want to check if there is any other way to use nested loops? like what I was trying to perform?